# How to get past broken bridge in Sunken Valley, not involving animated event?

Tags: sekiro-shadows-die-twice

After performing certain actions, you can

> kill Great Serpent in Sunken Valley,

which, after certain animated event, places you right on the other side of the destroyed bridge. Yet, I've managed to screw up, and fell into the water. No I have no idea how to get there second time, as

> Great Seprent is already dead.

So, is there any other way to get on the other side of this bridge?

If there is no way to get around, at least tell me, what item I'm gonna miss due to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the game hasn't saved yet when this happens, just kill the process and start again. You should be standing on the same rock you landed after you killed the serpent god.

That bridge has been an issue for a lot of people it seems. The collision box there is really wonky.

The most noteworthy thing is a dragon rot cure item, that's about it. nothing special there.

Comment: Well, as several days have already passed, you can guess, that I've saved long time ago, so possibility is skipped for me.